# KDE toolbar content dependent on activities

Tags: plasma5, kde5, kde-activities

So the developers excluded toolbars from activities and they are uniform among all activities. A lot was written about how they practically killed the idea of activities.

*But is there any **workaround** what so ever?* Like to make a different content of the tool bar for each activity or some grouping widgets (Quick Launcher, Folder View, etc.), which would be able to have different content for each activity?

BTW, for someone who knows KDE API and ways, it should be a job for a half an hour max, to adjust Quick Launcher and Folder View to have it's content Activity-dependent. Unfortunately, I only develop in .NET...

Comment: You could maybe file a feature request at https://bugs.kde.org.

Comment: That has been done, as far as my little research revealed. Developers turned it down. I didn't see the bug request itself, but number of angry posts and comments about it over various KDE-related internet discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so there was no response and I had to find at least partial solution myself.

So here is my advice to bring Activities at least partially to life (might be used as a complex settings or standalone tips):

1. Set desktops quantity to 1. It's not necessary, but with following settings each 
   activity will have it's own desktop, so they practically multiply.
2. Place a `Activity Preview` widget into your toolbar. Also, this is not necessary, 
   but if you're going to use Activities heavily, the `WIN-TAB` shortcut with following 
   clicking is quite awkward. With the `Activity Preview` widget, you can switch 
   Activity with 1 click.
3. Set the activities (i.e. `WIN-TAB`, click the options button at the top):

   a. Set required number of "fixed" Activities, perhaps with appropriate icons. 
       Activities can be also project or 
       task related, but I'm concerned about the long term Activities, that share 
       their workflow. To give you an idea, I set:

   ```
     * General (for all common tasks without specific workflow)
     * Admin - for administration - with YaST, KDE system settings, SuperUser 
       Dolphin, Kate, KInfo, nVidia shortcuts
     * Graphics - to work mostly with GIMP and InkScape
     * CAD - for 2D and 3D CAD work - LibreCAD and FreeCAD shortcuts
     * Devel - for programming
     * Web - for web development (shortcut to start Jekyll, shortcut to emulated 
       web, etc.
     * Writing - to work with Focus Writer, dictionary, ...
   ```

   b. On the 2nd tab called "Switching" check the checkbox "`Remember the current 
       virtual desktop for each activity (needs restart)`". Now I'm not sure if this 
       option is still required, when you set your desktop count to 1, but it doesn't 
       do any harm anyway.
4. I created a directory for Activities in my custom local Sys folder 
   (`~/Sys/Activities`) and 
   for each activity with standalone shortcut list another sub-directory, i.e. Admin, 
   Graphics, CAD,... I then opened the directories one by one and dragged there 
   shortcuts from the launcher in my panel and renamed them to more reasonable names 
   (i.e. "`org.kde.cervisia.desktop`" to "`Cervisia`").
5. For **EACH** activity desktop, I threw into the desktop one or two widgets called 
   `Folder View` and set them this way:

   a. If I used only one, I would set the `Folder View` widget to point to a working 
       directory of the activity, i.e. `~/Writing`, where I have *both* the 
       application shortcuts and the files. That is good for simple activities, such 
       as the writing.

   b. First of standalone `Folder View` is set to the particular folder created in 
       4th step. This way you see shortcuts for the Activity you have selected.

   c. Second of standalone widgets on the desktop is one to show files and folders 
       related to the activity, i.e. `~/Coding` for Devel Activity or`~/Graphics` for 
       Graphics Activity. Organise a special directory and help yourself with 
       `Symlinks`, if you have the work directories scattered over more places, such 
       as local and network.
6. For some applications you may set special behaviour on starting, let's say that you 
   might want GIMP to always start in Graphics Activity only. Then start GIMP, right 
   click the title bar, choose `Other Tasks` and then `Special window settings` and 
   in the `Size and location` tab, check the `Activity` checkbox and select `Initial 
   status` from the next combobox. But be careful not to set it to apps, that you 
   expect to use across activities, such as Dolphin or Konsole. However, the settings 
   above allows you to change the activities after you start the application, so you 
   can switch activity or add it to more activities (right-click app title bar and 
   select activities in local menu)
7. You should set the working directory mentioned before as Activities related 
   directory. Find the directory in Dolphin, select it's *content*, right-click it 
   and select `Activities` 
   and add it to current Activity or select one (or more) from the list. That is 
   required for following point
8. There's a way to set at least partially the task bar to reflect Activities. I use 
   for it a large side bar popping out of right edge of screen (whilst the main task 
   bar is at the classic bottom edge position. I have on this task bar some widgets 
   like clock and calendar and you can also add another `Folder View` here, this time 
   set it to `Show files related to active Activity`. Now, if you have set your files 
   and application shortcuts in appropriate working directories to particular 
   activities, the content of this widget will dynamically change according to the 
   selected activities.
9. There's a widget called Kargos, which I believe might be used to script stuff and 
   possibly it may by able to show Activity-related content. I didn't try it to set 
   up, so I can't help more.

This took me little bit of work to adjust, but it works reasonably for the activities I need. A factor is, that I have a large 4K screen and thus the `Folder View` widgets with app shortcuts are usually not covered, since I don't use most of my apps in full-screen mode. It might be an issue for a smaller screens.

I'd be pleased if you follow up this post with comments or answers that would help out to squeeze more good out of (currently quite crippled) activities.